# "Interface not supported" error when attempting to open Excel or Word from Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, ms-word

When using an old piece of Delphi code which outputs some text into Excel or Word, I encountered the error "Interface not supported" on one machine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that the previous version of Excel was uninstalled incorrectly on the machine. To fix it, I used the [following instructions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/dd052f27-20d6-4b6b-9d8b-fe4fd9c6b9fc) from Microsoft:

1. Open the regedit editor.
2. Open `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT >> TypeLib >> {00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`

(The Excel PIA key is `{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046})`
3. Delete the last version folder (Excel 2013 is 1.8, Excel 2016 is 1.9)

A similar [fix can be applied](https://www.polleverywhere.com/support/articles/troubleshooting-win/repair-powerpoint) to other Office products:

> **Excel**
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\
>
> - 1.7 is for Office 2010
> - 1.8 is for Office 2013
> - 1.9 is for Office 2016

> **Word** HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\
>
> - 8.5 is for Office 2010
> - 8.6 is for Office 2013
> - 8.7 is for Office 2016

> **PowerPoint** HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{91493440-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B}\
>
> - 2.a is for Office 2010
> - 2.b is for Office 2013
> - 2.c is for Office 2016

> **Outlook** HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\
>
> - 9.4 is for Office 2010
> - 9.5 is for Office 2013
> - 9.6 is for Office 2016

Here's a sample regedit file to fix the Registry for Office 2016:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9]
"PrimaryInteropAssemblyName"="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"
@="Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9\0]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9\0\win64]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9\FLAGS]
@="0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9\HELPDIR]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\8.7]
"PrimaryInteropAssemblyName"="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"
@="Microsoft Graph 16.0 Object Library"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\8.7\0]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\8.7\0\win64]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\MSWORD.OLB"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\8.7\FLAGS]
@="0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\8.7\HELPDIR]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

We had this same issue and found that: The above solution only works if office is physically installed, if you use O365 and it's click to run apps the above solution will not work. You will need to install the apps physically and not run them as click to run.

Answer (score 0):

Our client have the same problem. They are using DMR (Digital Mark Reader) application. The "Interface not supported" message is shown every time the user is exporting data to Excel. The Excel version is Office 2021. There is nothing wrong with the DMR Application.

We found that the solution is quite simple. Go to Settings or right click the Start button, find "Add Remove Programs" or "Apps and Features" or "Installed Apps", find and select Office, then select Modify, select Online Repair, not Quick Repair. Wait until completed then re-insert the serial number if needed.

I hope it works.

Source:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b